# htaccess file with Rewrite to work on any domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to block access to a specific file and the files in a specific directory and only allow them to be accessed when included or called etc from the server itself.

Currently I have an the htaccess file shown below at 'http://www.thedomain.com/.htaccess' to block access to 'http://www.thedomain.com/specific_file.php'

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?thedomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule specific_file.php$ / [R=302,L]
```

And an the htaccess file shown below at 'http://www.thedomain.com/thedir/.htaccess' to block access to all files in 'http://www.thedomain.com/thedir/'

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?thedomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .(gif|jpg|png|css|js|php|inc)$ / [R=302,L]
```

I'd like to be able to use these htaccess file on multiple domains without having to change the listed domain name. Is that possible?

And on a side note this code was cobbled together so any advice on improving it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why not just take the files you don't want available out of the web root?

Comment: @JonStirling — Since it is based on the REFERER, presumably because clients *should* be able to access it. This is a "prevent hot linking" exercise, not a "prevent access except by server side scripts" exercise.

Comment: Do you want to disallow hotlinking, e.g. disallow a foreign site to use your images? Or do you want to disallow access unless it is used on localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the final part of the RewriteCond use relative URLs instead of absolute ones, then it should work across any domain.

Answer (score 0):

check of referers is not secure way
I suggest that you upload yor specific file in a layer above the root path in this case Only You Have Access To uploaded file( In direct addressing) and an attacker have not access to it